# How to find which activity called another activity in my ADF Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline (LogPipeline) that logs other pipelines' status to a database. The idea is that every pipeline will call the LogPipeline at the start and at the end by passing pipeline name and pipeline ID along with other parameters like started/ended/failed.

The last parameter is "Reason" where I want to capture the error message of why a pipeline may have failed.

However, in a given pipeline there are multiple activities that could fail. So I want to direct any and all failed activities to my Execute Pipeline activity and pass the error message.

But on the Execute Pipeline when filling out the parameters, I can only reference an activity by its name, e.g. `Reason = @activity['Caller Activity'].Error.Message.`
However, since multiple activities are calling this Execute Pipeline, is there a way to say 
`Reason = @activity[activityThatCalledExecutePipeline].Error.Message?`

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct,there are multiple activities call the LogPipeline and you want to get those failed activities' names so that you could know the names inside LogPipeline. Per my knowledge,your requirement is not supported in ADF.

I'm not sure why you have to construct such complex scenario,even though you just want to log the specific fail activities and error messages anyway which is common requirement.There are many monitor ways supported by ADF,please follow below links:

1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#alerts

2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically

I would suggest you getting an idea of `Alerts and Monitor` in ADF portal:

[image]

And you could set the Target Criteria

[image]

It includes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to put a generic framwork that not only works for ADF pipelines but also a few pipelines in Snaplogic... and I wanted to make it as generic as possible...but doesnt look like ADF allows activity reflection.